# How to add two TextView inside ToolBar

Tags: android, layout

How to add two TextView inside ToolBar and set these position to rightside of toolbar?
Ive been looking on internet but i cant work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a regular layout with toolbar and add multiple TextViews inside,

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                    <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_header_view"
                    layout="@layout/header_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/header_view_end_margin_right"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

the **header_view** layout consists of 2 TextViews,

```
<!-- Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_view_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- Subtitle -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_view_sub_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: can i set auto margin like with different screen size or portrait/landscape mode ?

Comment: I didn't understand by auto-merging. Do you want to put the text center aligned?

Comment: i want to put text right side link image below https://s16.postimg.org/ap8uyx21h/image.png

Comment: i found that layout_gravity can handle my problems (i'm so new for coding). Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and set position of TextView according to your requirement

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_profile"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_toolbar_height"
      android:gravity="top|center"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/frame_detail_profile"
      app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
      app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
      app:title="">

      <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_toolbar_title_left_margin"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                android:text="@string/profile_username"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_toolbar_title_left_margin"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                android:text="@string/profile_username"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                 android:textSize="20sp" />           
             </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```